# IDA Pro: Program parameters

Tags: ida, shellcode

I am currently playing around with simple buffer overflows in a C program and I am trying to understand the program by stepping through it in IDA Pro.

The program takes an argument and writes it into a buffer with `strcpy()`. I can pass a simple argument like `AAAA...` to the program in IDA Pro (Debugger->process options) and see how the return address gets overwritten.

What I would like to do now is pass some shellcode as a parameter and see in IDA Pro how the program writes the shellcode in the buffer and overwrites the return address.

In a shell, I would execute something like:

```
$ ./vuln \`perl -e 'print "\x55\x89\xe5..."'`
```

or

```
$ ./vuln \`cat shellcode.txt`
```

So my question is: how can I pass non-printable characters as an argument to a program in IDA Pro?

Comment: Is it Linux or Windows ? Which debugger are you using ?

Comment: Its a Linux system and i am using the built-in debugger of IDA. So my debugging process looks like this: opening the program "vuln" in IDA (File->open), Debugger->Process options enter "AAA..." in the field "Process parameters" then hit F9 to run it.

Comment: You can try and use a shellcode encoder like https://code.google.com/p/alpha3/ to encode it in printable characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using IDC function `StartDebugger`. You can pass a C-style string (e.g. `"\x55\x89\xe5"`)for program arguments:

```
***********************************************
** Launch the debugger
   arguments:
        path - path to the executable file.
        args - command line arguments
        sdir - initial directory for the process
for all args: if empty, the default value from the database will be used
   returns: -1-failed, 0-cancelled by the user, 1-ok
   See the important note to the StepInto() function

long StartDebugger(string path, string args, string sdir);
```

Comment: when I start debuuger using following command idc.StartDebugger("/root/Documents/remote_debug/heapoverflow", "AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0001020304\x92\x91\x04\x08", "") IDA places hex charcters EFBDBFEF instead of that particular address

Comment: I am using remote debugging